# Sqlite bulk update is very slower even using transaction in my iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, transactions

It seems very weird.
When I insert thousands of records into a database with a transaction in my iPhone, the transaction can be completed around 1 seconds. But when I update the records I just inserted with a new transaction, It takes more than 10 seconds.
What I want to know is if the update operation in a transaction costs more time than insert operation?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you wrapping both of these in transactions? Are you updating an indexed field or not? Is your update in a single SQL statement, or are you looping through performing multiple SQL statements? Have you run `EXPLAIN` on the update SQL? It's hard for us to help you on the basis of the meager information provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rob. Finally I found the reason, it is because I did not add index to the field. Now it executes very fast after I added index to it. Thanks again.